# Using an object's method to sort a list of objects that contains the object

Tags: python, django

I have a problem.

I am trying to generate a list of objects of different types sorted by the object's "date". Each object has a method `getDate` which returns the date to sort by.

The `UserProfile` object contains a method `recent_activity` which should return this sorted list of objects.

However, see the line `#items.append(self)` in the below?

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    ...

    def getDate(self):
        return self.last_edited

    ...

    def recent_activity(self):

        followed = ...
        sponsored = ...
        ...

        items = []
        #items.append(self) #<-- If this is in, the call to sorted doesn't work

        for f in followed:
            if (...):
                items.append(f)
        for s in sponsored:
            if (...):
                items.append(s)
        for c in comments:
            if (...):
                items.append(c)
        for u in updates:
            if (...):
                items.append(u)
        for p in projects:
            items.append(p)

        #return items[0:7] #<-- If this is in, everything is fine!

        items = sorted(items, key=lambda item: item.getDate(),reverse=True)

        return items[0:7]
```

When I comment out the line `items.append(self)`, the code as written works perfectly, returning a (sliced) list of objects of different types sorted by date (using the `getDate()` method).

However, when this line is included, the code works intermittently - and I mean that for some objects it works (as above), and for some it does not (at all - in fact it often simply returns None).

If I return the array BEFORE calling `sorted`, again, everything works fine. So the problem is associated with the call to `sorted`.

Looking forward to hearing what I'm doing wrong!

(Just to be clear, someone has down-rated this question, I have no idea why - if you think it's unclear, please take the time to comment so I can improve the question!).

**Edit** - Now fixed. Solution was having occasional `getDate()` calls returning `datetime.date` objects rather than `datetime.datetime` objects because of a database migration causing me to manually populate some of the fields with the wrong type of object. Bit surprised to see no exceptions appear, just silent failing.

Comment: If it sometimes returns `None` you probably forgot to include a crucial piece of code people can use to make an educated guess at what's wrong. I don't know how the current code could return `None`.

Comment: Are the ones returning None for UserProfile objects that are not yet saved? Also, assuming followed, sponsored, comments, updates, projects are fields in the UserProfile object, it should be `for f in self.followed:`, `for s in self.sponsored:`, etc.

Comment: don't know if it helps but can't you just do "items = sorted(items, key=UserProfile.getDate,reverse=True)" ?

Comment: I also cannot see how the current code can return `None` - this is why I have posted the question here. My only theory is that calling `sorted` on list of items that includes a reference to the object that calls `sorted` might cause a problem with memory management (ie, there might be some bug in Python. Far-fetched though that theory is, I know). Furbeenator - the `followed` etc data structures are local to the method, I've added some code to show this. And no, all the UserProfile objects are saved already.

Comment: Arthur - I can't do that because the objects that I am sorting are of different types (they represent different "events") - the only thing they share is an implementation of `getDate` to enable them to be sorted. Thanks for help so far... really struggling with this one.

Answer (score 0):

Using pdb I managed to get to the root of the problem.

A couple of objects in my database had `datetime.date` objects stored in the field that was supposed to store `datetime.datetime` objects. The comparisons between these two types of object was failing during sorting, but failing silently.

I'm not sure why these comparisons in sorted did not generate an exception - in my view they should have.

Anyway, thanks for your suggestions.